# Strip symbols from static lib not referenced by other static lib

Tags: c++, visual-c++, gcc, clang

Is it possible to automatically remove symbols from static library A, if they are not referenced by another static library B? 
I.e. removing those symbols from A would would not be an issue for code in B.

Comment: Why can't you keep A the way it is and then strip them from B after the linking phase?

Comment: Try [Liposuction Tools](https://www.microsoft.com/msj/archive/S572.aspx) by Matt Pietrek.

Comment: @Simple Most toolchains are capable of stripping out unused symbols at link-time, but this happens before linking.